# Comparing DOB's from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g

SO I have to list the names of anyone in the tenant family who is older than the tenant itself. There are two tables. Tenant and tenant_family. I have tried comparing the two dates to see which DOB in the tenant_family table is less than (meaning they would be older) the DOB in the tenant table.

This is what I have so far but it appears to be wrong. Can someone direct me towards a way of getting the right output?

```
SELECT DISTINCT tenant_family.name
FROM TENANT_FAMILY, tenant
WHERE tenant_family.dob < tenant.TENANT_DOB;
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the result you expect to get? It's a bit hard to understand what you're gunning for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATE function to extract the date part of your query for comparison like:

`select distinct tenant_family.name from TENANT_FAMILY, tenant where DATE(tenant_family.dob) < DATE(tenant.TENANT_DOB);`

In case your `dob` and `TENANT_DOB` are not stored as the `DATE` data type in your database or they are stored as `DATETIME` then you might extract only the date part using the function:

`select distinct tenant_family.name from TENANT_FAMILY, tenant where date_format(tenant_family.dob,"%y-%m-%d") < date_format(tenant.TENANT_DOB,"%y-%m-%d);`

This should give you the correct results after comparison.

Comment: I just tried this and it gave me the error "missing expressions"

Comment: are you using Oracle 11G?